# Processing sketch crashes on PVector set

Tags: java, crash, processing

I've been working on a game in Processing and I came upon this problem: I'm trying to make a background with stars flying past and I have this class:

```
public class Star {
  PVector position;
  float speed;

  void draw() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(position.x, position.y, speed, speed);

    position.x -= speed;
  }

  public Star() {
    speed = random(5);
    position.set(width+speed,random(height));
  }
}
```

I have an ArrayList for Stars called stars:

```
ArrayList<Star> stars = new ArrayList<Star>();
```

I call the constructor in a function drawBg():

```
if(random(12) < 1) {
  stars.add(new Star());
}
```

But when drawBg is called and it creates a new Star(), the sketch crashes and it points to:

```
position.set(width+speed,random(height));
```

The IDE says "Could not run the sketch", and the console says:

> Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize). For more
>   information, read revisions.txt and Help ? Troubleshooting.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] that shows us the rest of your sketch, not just the `Star` class? We should be able to copy and paste your code to run it on our own machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your `position` variable is `null`, meaning it doesn't point to an instance of `PVector` yet.

You never **initialize** that variable (using the `new` keyword to create a new instance of `PVector`), so it's still `null` when you call `position.set()` in the `Star` constructor. That causes an error, since you can't call a function on a `null` variable.

To fix this, just use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of `PVector`:

```
public Star() {
    speed = random(5);
    position = new PVector(width+speed,random(height));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!